# java open source generate sql query from xml

Tags: java, sql, xml, frameworks

In java, do we have an open source to generate sql from an xml file? For example, the simplest case is :

```
<query>
  <select>id</select>
  <from>student</from>
   <equal><column>name</column><val>john</val></equal>
   <equal><column>age</column><val>23</val></equal>
   <equal><column>registerDate</column><val>03/04/1990</val></equal>
</query>
```

Then it will generate a sql:

```
select id
from student
where name = 'john'
    and age = 23
    and registerDate = '03/04/1990'
```

Of course, this is simplest case, when we have between, join, it will be more complex. So do we have an open source to handle this? I don't want to use ORM like hibernate, because it goes too far.

Thanks.

Comment: Hibernate serializes obects and stores these objects in a database. You can't compare hibernat to what you want to do ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure if there is. But why you need to put the query in a xml format. You can just simply put it in a sql file then call it in your DAO.

Comment: I am looking for the same thing. Please let me know if you have found some libraries, else we would have to write our own (and which is difficult as of now since we are chasing a deadline :( )

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use this XML format? Was it somehow internally defined?

If your objective on XML is purely making dynamic queries easier to create, you may try [MyBatis](http://www.mybatis.org/). It uses XML definition files to group the SQL queries together and allow you to dynamically change queries based on parameters, without the mess of assembling the SQL query with String concatenation. You won't define every element as a XML tag, but only parts of it that may change. Take a look at the [MyBatis User Guide](http://mybatis.googlecode.com/files/MyBatis-3-User-Guide.pdf) for more info and code samples. Here is a quick look at a simple dynamic query:

```
<select id=”findActiveBlogWithTitleLike” parameterType=”Blog” resultType=”Blog”>
    SELECT * FROM BLOG
    WHERE state = ‘ACTIVE’
    <if test=”title != null”>
        AND title like #{title}
    </if>
</select>
```

That's just to give you a glimpse of what it would look like. There are plenty of possibilities and tags to help you build whatever query you may need, so I suggest you to take some time to read the user guide to fully understand the framework capabilities.